# set ExpandableListView checkboxes checked when initializing

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, expandablelistview

I am using this script for an expandable listview with checkboxes.
https://github.com/bhat-dinesh/ExpandableListViewWithCheckBox

It works awesome, i also managed to get the specific checkboxes state to save in my shared preferences.

But now the problem is i want to load the checkboxes state when the activity is initializing. Like i saved the states of every checkbox in a shared preferences file. Now i want to load this SharedPreferences file and enable the checkboxes which should be enabled in this activity.

I know how to load the SharedPref file, and how to get data out of it.
But how do i enable the checkboxes when initializing?

Answer (score 0):

From first look at the source, you have object: *mChildCheckStates*  in your adapter class, that contains the check states.

**To do what you need, Use the constructor or write a function to change them.**

Also, I dont know how you will decide to proceed, but if you just started with adapters, make sure to look at this function: *void notifyDataSetChanged ()*